# SQL Server manage column descriptions by script

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to alter/update and drop/delete column descriptions via script?

I use `sp_addextendedproperty` to add description, but it does not allow update. When I try to use same sp to update an existing description value, it says something like "description property already exists"

Both alter or drop/create like solutions are ok for me.

### SOLUTION

After helpful answers and comments, you can see my final solution below. May help someone.

```
create procedure sp_set_column_description (
    @schema varchar(256),
    @table varchar(256),
    @column varchar(256),
    @description varchar(256))
    as
begin
    if exists (
        select p.* 
        from
            sys.extended_properties p, 
            sys.columns c, 
            sys.tables t, 
            sys.schemas s
        where
            t.schema_id = s.schema_id and
            c.object_id = t.object_id and
            p.major_id = t.object_id and
            p.minor_id = c.column_id and
            p.name = N'MS_Description' and 
            s.name = @schema and
            t.name = @table and
            c.name = @column
    )
        exec sys.sp_updateextendedproperty 
            @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=@schema,
            @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=@table,
            @level2type=N'COLUMN', @level2name=@column,
            @name=N'MS_Description', @value=@description
    else
        exec sys.sp_addextendedproperty 
            @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=@schema,
            @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=@table,
            @level2type=N'COLUMN', @level2name=@column,
            @name=N'MS_Description', @value=@description
end

go

create procedure sp_drop_column_description (
    @schema varchar(256),
    @table varchar(256),
    @column varchar(256))
    as
begin
    if exists (
        select p.* 
        from
            sys.extended_properties p, 
            sys.columns c, 
            sys.tables t, 
            sys.schemas s
        where
            t.schema_id = s.schema_id and
            c.object_id = t.object_id and
            p.major_id = t.object_id and
            p.minor_id = c.column_id and
            p.name = N'MS_Description' and 
            s.name = @schema and
            t.name = @table and
            c.name = @column
    )
        exec sys.sp_dropextendedproperty 
            @level0type=N'SCHEMA', @level0name=@schema,
            @level1type=N'TABLE', @level1name=@table,
            @level2type=N'COLUMN', @level2name=@column,
            @name=N'MS_Description'
end
```

Comment: I believe there is a corresponding update proc: `sp_updateextendedproperty`

Comment: Seems like there are `sp_updateextendedproperty` and `sp_dropextendedproperty`. I will try them.

Comment: `sp_updateextendedproperty` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186885.aspx

Comment: drop and update procedures throw exception if property not exists and add sp throws exception if property already exists. I tried `try add catch update` logic but somehow it causes a database lock. After executing a 'rollback' lock disappeared but dealing with transactions for this simple operation is unnecessarily complicated. It would be better we could check if extended property exists.

Comment: Would [sys.fn_listextendedproperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179853.aspx) help?

Comment: Thanks for the useful answer.  [Here is a slight variation](https://gist.github.com/tom-haines/e498fb0bde88991dde9446053d854780#file-util_set_comments-sql) that follows the current schema (i.e. uses `select @SchemaName = SCHEMA_NAME()`).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Combined with Steph Locke's suggestion, you can check for existence of the extended proc using:

```
if exists(
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    sys.extended_properties p
            join sys.columns c on p.major_id = c.object_id and p.minor_id = c.column_id 
    where   p.major_id = OBJECT_ID('yourtablename','table')
            and p.name = 'Description'  
)
```

Comment: Why `SELECT  top 1 1`? It looks horrible and is no better than `SELECT *`

Comment: Habit.  I do that when creating a semi-join with "exists."  I am under the impression that in *that* case, it makes a performance difference.  In the above example, it clearly doesn't.

Comment: @Martin Smith Interesting stuff, thank you for that.  I try to avoid unecessary fluff in my SQL code, so I will scratch that one.  Edited my answer.