# Remove the int dynamically from create table using preg_replace

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

How do I remove the int dynamically using preg_replace function in php?

I have the following code

```
CREATE TABLE vtiger_meter ( meterid int(11) DEFAULT NULL, meterno int(8) DEFAULT NULL, cdate date DEFAULT NULL, address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, customer varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )
```

And I want the following code

```
CREATE TABLE vtiger_meter ( meterid int DEFAULT NULL, meterno int DEFAULT NULL, cdate date DEFAULT NULL, address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, customer varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )
```

I want like about output. After int there must a dynamic value I want to remove that one. How to do this any suggestion?

I do with custom function explode but I want using this in preg_replace.

Comment: Is it valid to not specify a length for the int field?  That is what the number in the parens that you want to remove is.  It is an instruction to the database to set that int column up to allow numbers with up to 11 places.  Without it, the database will either pick a default, or it will not create the table.

Comment: Yes you are right im just saying for an example how to remove it ?? dynamically after int the field can have any number i want to rmeove that one

Answer (score 1):

```
$input = 'CREATE TABLE vtiger_meter (
            meterid int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
            meterno int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
            cdate date DEFAULT NULL,
            address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
            customer varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )';
$output = preg_replace('/int\s*\(\s*\d+\s*\)/', 'int ', $input);
echo $output;
```

Comment: In mysql it is possible to do show create table tablename

what is the mssql server 2008 equivalent?

Comment: I have no idea, I don't use sql-server.

Answer (score 1):

Using preg_replace, replace `int\(\d+\)\s*` with `int`.

```
$statement = preg_replace('/int\(\d+\)\s*/', 'int ', $statement);
```

Notice the space after 'int'.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$str = "CREATE TABLE vtiger_meter ( meterid int(11) DEFAULT NULL, meterno int(25534) DEFAULT NULL, cdate date DEFAULT NULL, address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, customer varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )";
preg_replace("/ int\s*\(\s*([0-9]+)\s*\\)/", " int ", $str);
print $str;
```

Output is

like

```
CREATE TABLE vtiger_meter ( meterid int DEFAULT NULL, meterno int DEFAULT NULL, cdate date DEFAULT NULL, address varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL, customer varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL )
```

For more detail please see this link https://www.php.net/preg_replace

Comment: In mysql it is possible to do show create table tablename

what is the mssql server 2008 equivalent?

Comment: yes. Please see this link for more detail http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131327.aspx
   
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586842/sql-comments-on-create-table-on-sql-server-2008

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace only `int` but not `tinyint` or `longint` and all of these, you could do (using a word boundary `\b` and do the replace case-insensitive)

```
$str = preg_replace('/\bint\(\d+\)/i', 'int', $str);
```