# Is it possible to add description for column while creating table in MSSQL QUERY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to add description for column while creating table in MSSQL QUERY. I am in need to add description for columns in table while moving data to the table.

Comment: The descriptions are extended properties (I believe the name is literally `MSDescription`) and can be set with `sp_addextendedproperty`/`sp_updateextendedproperty` and retrieved with `fn_listextendedproperty`. There is no direct support within DDL statements for them (`CREATE TABLE`, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clunky in SQL Server. For some reason, they've never adopted the `COMMENT` syntax, and you can't add the comments directly in the `CREATE TABLE` statement.

After your `CREATE` statement, run the system stored procedure [sp-addextendedproperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addextendedproperty-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

There's an extended conversation on the topic under this question: [SQL Comments on Create Table on SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4586842/sql-comments-on-create-table-on-sql-server-2008)